# JavaScript array of array of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Currently I am having a problem with JavaScript arrays where if I update a value in an array it updates the value in both arrays.

My current array looks like this

```
billarr[camp][e].dataa = t;
```

For example if you try update the array like

```
billarr[22][1].dataa = "blabla";
```

It updates the dataa value in both

```
billarr[22]
```

and

```
billarr[23]
```

to the dataa var being "blabla"

I have spent hours looking what is the possible solution and am desperate if anyone has any advice

array population code

```
message ={};
temparr4 =[];

message.typee= $("#type"+data[i].id).val(); 
message.events= $("#event"+data[i].id).val(); 
message.network=data[i].network; 
message.network_des=data[i].network_des; 
message.dataa=data[i].data; 

temparr4[data[i].id]=message;
```

and then loop(sets default array content)

```
camparr.forEach(function(i,e) {
billarr[e] = temparr4;

});
```

without using objects still has same array update issue.

message =[];
    temparr4 =[];

```
message[0]= $("#type"+data[i].id).val(); 
message[1]= $("#event"+data[i].id).val(); 
message[2]=data[i].network; 
message[3]=data[i].network_des; 
message[4]=data[i].data; 

temparr4[data[i].id]=message;
```

and then loop(sets default array content)

```
camparr.forEach(function(i,e) {
billarr[e] = temparr4;

});
```

This still updates both arrays billarr[22] and billarr[23]

```
billarr[camp][e][4] = t;
```

I have updates with code using no objects and just arrays but the array does the same as object and updates both arrays at specific element

Comment: None of that really makes sense. Can you clarify please? Maybe provide an example?

Comment: Could billarr[22] and billarr[23] be refs to the same object? Can you show how you construct the arrays?

Comment: I would recommend you to reproduce the problem with a smaller array and then post the code so we may test it out and give you advices.

Comment: camparr is just an array of id's eg 22, 23 as its populated from data we select.

Comment: @Liam [check most recent JS versions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

Comment: Updated without using objects but same problem :(

Answer (score 3):

You're constructing your array incorrectly, and storing the **same** object in two places in the array, rather than storing two *separate* objects.

You haven't shown nearly enough of your code for us to help you with it, but here's an example:

```
// An array
var a = [];

// An object
var o = {data: "foo"};

// Putting that object in the array
a.push(o);

// Putting it in again -- this results in the *same* object being in the array twice
a.push(o);

// If we change object...
a[0].data = "bar";

// ...it's the *object* that gets changed, so it doesn't matter which
// reference we use when looking at it:
console.log(a[0].data); // "bar"
console.log(a[1].data); // "bar"
console.log(o.data);    // "bar"
```

The solution is to create a *new* object after pushing the old one onto the array

```
// An array
var a = [];

// An object
var o = {data: "foo"};

// Putting that object in the array
a.push(o);

// Creating a *new* object
o = {data: "testing"};

// Pushing the new object in the array
a.push(o);

// If we change object...
a[0].data = "bar";

// ...the other object isn't changed:
console.log(a[0].data); // "bar"
console.log(a[1].data); // "testing"
```

Comment: Thanks I suspected it was using same object. However I have the problem of having to store the array id where push gives next number. 

message ={};
temparr4 =[];

message.typee= $("#type"+data[i].id).val(); 
message.events= $("#event"+data[i].id).val(); message.network=data[i].network; message.network_des=data[i].network_des; 
message.dataa=data[i].data; 

temparr4[data[i].id]=message; 

and then loop

camparr.forEach(function(i,e) {
            billarr[e] = temparr4;

        });

Comment: @ koeks: You're storing the **same** array (the one referenced by `temparr4`) repeatedly in your `forEach` callback.

Comment: That should be fine, its just setting the default info in the array which will be altered if needed with the update, however the update on billarr[22] updates billarr[23] too which is my issue with the object

Comment: @ koeks: And if something alters that one array?

Comment: It updates the object on both arrays as I just edited above :)

Comment: @ koeks: Right. ***The*** object. So if you want the objects to be independent of one another, you need to create *separate* objects. Same with the arrays. Unless you want `billarr[22].push(...)` to affect the array that's stored both in `billarr[22]` and `billarr[23]`, you need to create *different* arrays.

Comment: Thanks, Can I create an array of the objects to use that would work?

Comment: Also If I get rid of the objects and just use arrays why does it also update both arrays?

Comment: @ koeks: I recommend you step back from your current task and just play with objects and arrays a bit in a nice simple setup. Arrays *are* objects. You need to stop thinking about an object getting updated "...in both (places)". It doesn't. **The**, single, object is updated, and you are *referring* to that object from two different places. The answer is to stop doing that, as shown above.